# KIBANA on K8S restart after plugin installation

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, cloud, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I installed the opendistro alerting plugin in my kibana running on k8s deployment from the lifecycle postart, the installation is successful , but in the UI of kibana i can't see the plugin  buttons , so after searching it appears that i have to restart the kibana that is running on a pod , how can i achieve that without losing the image that has the plugin installed,because restarting the pod makes me lose the previous image and the installation happens again ,Am running kibana 7.10.2

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve this using init containers and related stuff, basically try to find out what the install is doing and mimic those changes. A cleaner approach, also the recommended way by Elastic, is to bring your own image:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-kibana-plugins.html

Comment: Is there any sample to get the Kibana pod working with initContainers, not with a custom image?